CRYPTICROSS
You’ve been framed for the heist of a famous painting! Can you sort out the clues and come up with a convincing alibi?
Solve it on Penpa+!
Note: Although not necessary to solve this puzzle, the formatting is better in this Google Doc.

Clues:
 Wild pig features in promotion on vehicle? (6)
 A great Greek warrior whose heel would not heal (8)
 America's Pledge (10)
 The one-person company that manufactured the Mitchell Wing A-10 (11)
 The Southern Slavic “Fried Chicken Capital of the World” (9)
 The bounds of a measure, or places where you might see a bouncer (8)
 Like Bach's extravagant ornamentation? (7)
 Manner of listening in Stanford concert hall? (7)
 The former home of PHENIX, PHOBOS, and BRAHMS (10)
 Even a chaplain from Reno is a state? (10)
 Possessor of carnassials and long canines (9)
 Dishonest cat makes happy noise, turns around in bed? (7)
 True of the integers and rationals, but not the irrationals or reals (9)
 Sherlock Holmes' favorite level of schooling (10)
 Particularly found in Japanese special lyrics? (10)
 Overseer of one quintillion excavators? (8)
 Correspondence after iron lady? (6)
 Travel steadily back from wild dog? (4)
 I heard olive oil is popular here? (6)
 A mandated stretch of undeveloped greenery near urban areas (9)
 Courageous woman loses feet to drug? (6)
 The instrument used to study aether drag and gravitational waves (14)
 An invertible map that shows two structures are "basically the same" (11)
 A British fifth-rate frigate in the background of Capture of La Minerve off Toulon (10)
 Sounds like stonks for Elijah or Ezekiel? (7)
 Body system messes with story repair? (11)
 A consonant pronounced by bending the tongue back (9)
 Scheherazade's key to survival (12)
 Undo misdeed after X sport? (6)
 Stare at timekeeping device? (5)
It's time to sort out the clues:
 _______ _ ______ __ ______ _____ _______? (6 6)
 ____________ __ _ ______ _______ __ ____ (6 7)
What were you doing while the heist was taking place?
 

Although not a part of the puzzle, anyone that recognizes the color palette gets a brownie point from me :)

"This puzzle requires colored text, which you should view at this Google Doc" -- do you mean that solving the puzzle requires one to read that Google Doc? That would be a problem: puzzles here need to be self-contained and not depend on specific external resources that might go away (or that some solvers might be unable to use).

@GarethMcCaughan The puzzle is solvable without the Google Doc. However, I believe the solver's experience will be improved if they choose to view the version with colored text.

@GarethMcCaughan I've edited the blurb.

Thanks. Can you briefly describe what coloured text is viewable in the Google Doc? E.g., are some parts of the clues coloured, or something like that?

... I had a look at the doc. It looks as if: (1) some clues are red and some blue; (2) the two solution-spaces after "It's time to sort out the clues" are red (first) and blue (second); (3) spaces for the final answer are red (6), purple (6), blue (7). Is there any reason why the relevant information can't be edited into the puzzle text here, even if actually making things the right colour is inconvenient? (I think it could be done using MathJax, in principle.)

I have no objection to doing said editing but I'm reluctant to mess with someone else's puzzle. (And also I have to go to bed fairly soon because I need to be up early tomorrow morning.)

Clue colours (for others' information): 1 red, 5 blue, 2 red, 1 blue, 1 red, 1 blue, 1 red, 2 blue, 5 red, 1 blue, 1 red, 3 blue, 2 red, 2 blue, 2 red.

@GarethMcCaughan I'll give it a whirl once I get to my computer

@bobble Thanks for the feedback! I've edited in all the necessary color information. The only thing missing is the coloring of the title, which I'm not sure how to add. In any case, that's present for theming, and isn't strictly necessary to solve the puzzle.

First of all let's solve the nonogram picross. It's reasonably straightforward so I haven't recorded the steps along the way.

 

And let's solve the clues

 where the red ones are cryptics and the blue ones are just definitions

giving

r ABOARD [BOAR in AD] Wild pig features in promotion on vehicle? (6)
b ACHILLES A great Greek warrior whose heel would not heal (8)
b ALLEGIANCE America's Pledge (10)
b AMERIPLANES The one-person company that manufactured the Mitchell Wing A-10 (11)
b BARBERTON The Southern Slavic “Fried Chicken Capital of the World” (9)
b BARLINES The bounds of a measure, or places where you might see a bouncer (8)
r BAROQUE [ddef] Like Bach<'s> extravagant ornamentation? (7)
r BEARING [EAR in BING] Manner of listening in Stanford concert hall? (7)
b BROOKHAVEN The former home of PHENIX, PHOBOS, and BRAHMS (10)
r CALIFORNIA [alternate letters] Even a chaplain from Reno is a state? (10)
b CARNIVORE Possessor of carnassials and long canines (9)
r CORRUPT [PURR< in COT] Dishonest cat makes happy noise, turns around in bed? (7)
b COUNTABLE True of the integers and rationals, but not the irrationals or reals (9)
b ELEMENTARY Sherlock Holmes' favorite level of schooling (10)
r ESPECIALLY [substring] Particularly found in Japanese special lyrics? (10)
r EXAMINER [exa-miner] Overseer of one quintillion excavators? (8)
r FEMALE [Fe + mail/male] Correspondence after iron lady? (6)
r FLOW [WOLF<] Travel steadily back from wild dog? (4)
r GREECE [homophone of GREASE, def is whole clue] I heard olive oil is popular here? (6)
b GREENBELT A mandated stretch of undeveloped greenery near urban areas (9)
r HEROIN [HEROIN(-e)] Courageous woman loses feet to drug? (6)
b INTERFEROMETER The instrument used to study aether drag and gravitational waves (14)
b ISOMORPHISM An invertible map that shows two structures are "basically the same" (11)
b LOWESTOFFE A British fifth-rate frigate in the background of Capture of La Minerve off Toulon (10)
r PROPHET [homophone] Sounds like stonks for Elijah or Ezekiel? (7)
r RESPIRATORY [(STORY REPAIR)*] Body system messes with story repair? (11)
b RETROFLEX A consonant pronounced by bending the tongue back (9)
b STORYTELLING Scheherazade's key to survival (12)
r TENNIS [TEN + SIN<] Undo misdeed after X sport? (6)
r WATCH [ddef] Stare at <> timekeeping device? (5)

What next? Well, after a bit of thought

 we notice that (1) there are 15 nonogram rows, 15 red clues, and 15 blue clues; (2) red + blue = purple; and (3) the total number of letters in all the red solutions = the total number of red + purple cells in the nonogram, and the total number of letters in the blue solutions = the total number of blue + purple cells in the nonogram.

So

 it looks like we are pairing up the red and blue clues, each nonogram row getting one of each, so that they overlap correctly when we write the red solution in the red+purple cells and the blue solution in the blue+purple cells.

This isn't too painful to do:

 e.g., we can start by putting in INTERFEROMETER, the only 14-letter word, and then HEROIN, the only red of the form ----IN. (As it happens, I actually solved that clue only later, but I knew which one it had to be because I had solutions for the others and they didn't end -IN.)

The fiddliest bit was

 when e.g. I had three red 7s left and three spaces where they could go, but this was just a matter of seeing which ones put something usable in the purple spaces.

We end up with this:

 

and now

 we can read off the highlighted letters to get the two intermediate clues represented in the question by dashes: red "Espying a couple of broken siege engines (6,6)" and blue "Barbenheimer is a recent example of this". In keeping with the convention noted earlier, the red one is a cryptic yielding SEEING SEEING which we are probably supposed to apply a further step of interpretation to to get SEEING DOUBLE, and the blue one a straight definition yielding DOUBLE FEATURE.

Note on the foregoing:

 I'm not sure it's quite sound to have wordplay that produces SEEING SEEING and have the answer be SEEING DOUBLE. The definition part of the clue fits better with SEEING DOUBLE and that also works better for the next step in the puzzle, but the wordplay definitely doesn't directly make that. (Thanks to Matthieu M. in comments for pointing out that I rather skated over this particular oddity in the previous version of this answer.)

And finally

 we put these together with overlap: red (6) purple (6) blue (7): SEEING DOUBLE FEATURE (where I guess it's sort of coincidence, but quite possibly a deliberate one, that SEEING DOUBLE is also a meaningful phrase).

So our alibi is

 that we were SEEING a DOUBLE FEATURE at the local movie theatre.


Congratulations, that was fast!

Thanks. It was fun, except for one clue with an unindicated homophone in it :-).

By the way, the overlap mechanic applies to the title as well, which has color pattern RRRPRPPBBBB

I hadn't even noticed that the title was coloured :-).

But, having seen that, I shall go and correct the word "nonogram" in my solution writeup.

Fubhyq gur erq pyhr lvryq FRRVAT QBHOYR, engure guna FRRVAT FRRVAT? Gurer'f ab bireync bgurejvfr.

Maybe. The wordplay definitely leads to rot13(FRRVAT FRRVAT) but maybe we are supposed to do another step of processing after it, so to speak. I'll edit my answer to try to clarify the situation. [EDITED to add:] Now done. Thanks!
